# How can I select a subarea of an image with mouse and make it a new image?

Tags: dm-script

I want to get *some subarea of an image* and make it a new image, and then execute further functions on it.

How can I **use mouse** to select a subarea of an image?
I know `img[]` could get the subarea of `img`, but I need some function by which I can interact with `img`. I mean, I want to get a WYSIWYG effect.

Is there any commands available, or is there any methods of ROI capable?

Answer (score 0):

There different ways to do what you want in a script: You could ask the user to place an ROI and then use the [] to address this area. If you want to get a new image from this selection (`CTRL + C` and `CTRL + SHIFT + V` without scripting) you would write:

> `ShowImage( ImageClone( img[] ) )`
> or
> `img[].ImageClone().ShowImage()`

If you want to place a ROI for the user, you can used `SetSelection()` for a simple, rectangle, volatile ROI, or you use the full ROI commands like in this example:

```
image img := RealImage( "Test", 4, 256, 256 )      // create image
img.ShowImage()                                    // show the image (so that it has a display)
imageDisplay disp = img.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)    // Get the 'display' of an image 

ROI myR = NewRoi()                                 // create ROI
myR.ROISetRectangle( 110, 120, 130, 140 )          // Make it a rectangle of given area
myR.ROISetVolatile( 0 )                            // make it non-volatile
myR.ROISetLabel( "Selection" )                     // give it a label
myR.ROISetColor( 0, 1, 0 )                         // make it green

disp.ImageDisplayAddROI( myR )                     // add it to the display
```

A full list of ROI commands can be found in the following section of the F1 help documentation:

[image: ROI help]

Comment: Uhhh!!  
How silly I was!..  
I even didn't well define my problem..  

I could just put in the script a prompt, and click the "Rectangle ROI" in the toolbar to add an any-size ROI (and resize it if necessary).  
What I want is a listener, which passes the control to the script after I create and resize the ROI.  

Or, I don't even need the listener. Before the script execute, I can tell my teacher to add the ROI, cause it's the first step of my script.

As for the listener, there is already a question asked here.
Sorry for my silly question..